# FOC Motor Control Algorithm - ADC sampling

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I'm working on implementing the FOC motor control algorithm on an STM32F411 microcontroller. My question is about when you need to sample the phase currents in relation to your PWM pulses. If you turn on the transistors, you'll get an increasing current ramp over the course of your PWM on time (due to the inductance of the motor coils), so how are you supposed to know what the three different phases are doing if they all take their ADC measurements at (about) the same time? The FOC algorithm requires us to sample ADC's in the center of a PWM pulse to best approximate the current through a phase, but how can I get the ADC measurements to line up with one another if all three PWM signals need to be operating independently? Is this confusion due to using edge aligned PWM vs center aligned? Can anyone point me to a paper on how to pull this off?

Thanks and regards,
Craig

Comment: I do not have a paper for you, but you could consider sampling your current faster than your switching frequency. Then, looking at the slope and knowing the duty cycle of your control, you can deduce an average current.  STM32F4 have DMA, you could take advantage of that.

Comment: Do you have a shunt on each phase or just one shunt on the negative side of your fets?

Comment: I'm using 2 shunts on phases A and B between the source of my low side FETs and ground. I'm sampling the ADC constantly but I'm only using the last measurement to feed my PI current controller algorithm. Do you think that is a mistake? I'm not sure whether that error signal should be generated based on all the ADC samples I see between PWM update cycles or only using the last sample. I've got all PWM signals being generated off different CCR values on timer 1 (using up/down mode for center align). I'm making progress but it's not quite there yet. Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to organize my answer on points rather than cramming it into an essay :)

1- As far as i know most people use center aligned PWM in motor control applications.

2- All three PWM signals and there inverse, have the same time base ( main timer ) so they are synchronized even if they have different values (hence they are not independent).

3-The values of the ADC should be sampled at one time , not each of them at the middle of its respective PWM signal. A lot of modern MCU allow for sampling multiple signals at the same time, and conversion is sequential .

4- motor control micro-controller (not sure about STM32F411) use a special event trigger ( microchip calls it that ) that lets the adc sample and covert automatically when the PWM time base reaches a certain value. which could be the start or end of the PWM cycle

5-I would advice you to take a look at TI motor control app notes, STM32 motor control library , and microchip [AN1078 Sensorless Field Oriented Control of a PMSM](http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en530042) , [AN1292](http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en544825) , [AN1162](http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en533872) , [AN1206](http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en536065) . with PDF that explains the concept and C code for more details

Regards